# preg_match not working on long regular expressions

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to match a keyword using preg_match in php.
regular expression is working perfectly on www.regexr.com but not in my php code. can someone help. Thankyou.

```
<?php

$regexx="/[sS]+([\s\t\r]*[\.\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\[\]\{\}\;\:\"\'\\\|\,\.\<\>\/\?\d\w]*)+[hH]+([\s\t\r]*[\.\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\[\]\{\}\;\:\"\'\\\|\,\.\<\>\/\?\d\w]*)+[aA]*([\s\t\r]*[\.\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\[\]\{\}\;\:\"\'\\\|\,\.\<\>\/\?\d\w]*)+[rR]*([\s\t\r]*[\.\~\`\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\=\[\]\{\}\;\:\"\'\\\|\,\.\<\>\/\?\d\w]*)+[eE]*
/";
if (preg_match($regexx, "S-hare"))
{
    echo 'succeeded';
}
else
{
    echo 'failed';
}

?>
```

Comment: Can we assume `S-hare` is the string that is matching in regexr but not in PHP? We also need a description of the pattern you are trying to match so we can suggest fixes.

Comment: I want to match the word 'share' written in any format. for example.. any special character or space in between 'share' would be detected.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> I want to match the word 'share' written in any format. for example.. any special character or space in between 'share' would be detected.

I would suggest to simply remove every non alphabetics characters then match what is left.

```
var_dump($str = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i", "", "sh@a/#~r:  e !!!"));
var_dump($str === "share");
```

A raw single regex solution could be:
`/[^a-z]*s[^a-z]*h[^a-z]*a[^a-z]*r[^a-z]*e[^a-z]*/i`
Which is simple share and `[^a-z]*` to match any non alphabetics series of characters between every letters.

Comment: Thankyou So much. It really helped me.
Please do some more help.
I want to match the word 'share' in a line.
Can you help me doing this?

Comment: **Thank you very much**

Comment: Accept answer and +1 are the common way of saying thx on stackoveflow :) So other people sees what answer was usefull.